# Hiding subfolders from URL through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I hide all subfolders from the URLs on my site?

So `http://www.example.com/whatever` just shows as `http://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this into you htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

All your request will be rewritten to index.php, which will achieves what you're describing.

Comment: That seems to just redirect every page back to index.php.  I dont want to redirect every page, I just want the their subfolders to not show in the url.

Comment: Okay, so I don't understand what you want

Comment: I want the url to be the exact same in the address bar, no matter what page on my website you are viewing.  It never changes, just always displays http://www.example.com whether Im viewing the About page, or the Gallery page.  It always displays the same url in the address bar...That's what I want.

Comment: Oh, okay, i understand what you want. You're looking for a single page application (SPA). The basics are you're using # (anchor) in your html, or html5mode to have 'real' URLs. In the first case, you don't have to make a special configuration on the server.